# (Stripe) Change existing plan's free trial period, how does it affect the users subscribed to the plan beforehand

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently using two plans - 'Monthly' and 'Yearly'. They both have a 45-day free trial.

I want to remove the free trial so that every new user is immediately charged, however, I don't want anything to change for all old users.

I am using Stripe.

I am asking does changing existing plans' free trial period affect the users' subscriptions to the plans (with free trial)?

Update:

I saw that in the Plans documentation on Stripe's website there is a paragraph regarding this - "Once a plan has been created, only the metadata and statement description can be modified; the amount, currency, and interval are fixed. Should you need to change any of these parameters, a new plan must be created instead.", however the free_trial is not mentioned.

I believe it is considered metadata, since it is editable, but I don't how the change will be handled. Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran a couple of tests.

It turns out you are able to change the trial period of a plan. This will result in already made subscriptions not being changed, however, new ones being affected.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr is once a plan is created, you can't change much.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_plan

--

You'd need to create a new plan if you'd like to change the cost or parameters such as trial. Existing users will be unaffected. If you were to delete an existing plan, those on it would remain active and grandfathered on the old plan, you simply could not add new users to that plan.

Comment: If that is the case, how come am I allowed to edit it?
                  
                  
    https://s1.postimg.org/5q9xpn8vvj/imageedit_2_4361824177.png

Comment: That's interesting, perhaps unexpected as trials on plans seem mostly depreciated! The bottom line is any changes to the trial on a plan object will not impact _existing_ subscriptions, only new ones going forward.